# How can you add in Javascript resources at the very bottom of an xpage?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I need to include a javascript file right at the end of the xpage so it gets loaded after the XSP.addOnLoad event code which is generated automatically  e.g.

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
XSP.attachEvent....
}
<script src="my.js">
```

Ideally I want to include it as part of a theme but if I do that it goes into the HEAD section

So can I either..
-Specify in a theme to insert the link to a client side js resource at the bottom of the page rather than the head
-Include a resource on an xpage directly so it goes after the auto-generated code

NB: This it needed in order to get an xpages app working with Foundations
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/

I need to include the foundations js file after the events have been bound to the fields

Thanks!

Comment: Just because the script tag is at the end of the page does not mean it will trigger in that sequence - the script will start to run as the page is loaded - the dojo.onLoad event (in XSP.addOnLoad) will start to fire after the page is fully loaded - i.e. AFTER the foundations script library has been loaded.

Ideally you need a trigger to find out when the XSP.addOnLoad has finished. The answer to that question would help you.

looking at the foundations site - if everything is initialized in the apps.js then your trigger would run the apps.js code rather than having it run itself.

Comment: Yes turns out I had the problem all wrong anyway.  The events were firing but the jquery code was bombing out due to the colons in the ids. by chance I stumbled upon your xsnippet which helped me fix the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a script block in the end with this code:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
  document.write('<script src="my.js">');
}
```

However this may execute before the generated `XSP.addOnLoad`. You could then try a small hack like this:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
  setTimeout(document.write('<script src="my.js">'), 200);
}
```

Comment: Cheers.  I can see how that would have worked but turned out I had mis-diagnosed the problem. see my other comment - was due to foundations code erroring rather than not being called at the right time.  Thanks for your help tho!